# Ember handling multiple returns?

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js

I have two json inputs,

Input 1 :

```
var status = [{
isLogged : true   
}];
```

Input2 :

```
var posts = [{
id: '1',
datalink:124,
isVoted : true,
votecount : 123,
title: "Rails is Omakase",
author: { name: "d2h" },
date: new Date('12-27-2012'),
excerpt: "There are lots of à la carte software environments in this world. Places where in order to eat, you must first carefully look over the menu of options to order exactly what you want."
}]
```

Everything worked fine when there was one json,

```
App.Route = Ember.Route.extend({
    model : function(){
    return posts;
    }
});
```

But when I added the second input it doesn't work

```
App.Route = Ember.Route.extend({
    model : function(){
    return posts;
    },
    logged : function(){
        return status;
    }
});
```

How can I get the second input and disply in the html?

```
{{#if isLogged}}
<li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
{{else}}
<li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the second input into your Route's controller.

```
App.Route = Ember.Route.extend({
    model : function(){
        return posts;
    },
    setupController(controller, model){
        controller.set("model", model);
        controller.set("isLogged", status);
    }
});
```

And since the `isLogged` will be declared in the controller, it should be visible within the view.

Comment: if this answered correctly to your question don't forget to mark it as the good answer ! :)